# Making jaxb lines generic to avoid writing them repeatedly

Tags: jaxb

Unmarshalling from a `File`:

```java
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   Object o = u.unmarshal( new File( "nosferatu.xml" ) );
```

Unmarshalling from an `InputStream`:

```java
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream( "nosferatu.xml" );
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   Object o = u.unmarshal( is );
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) APIs are already quite generic.

**JAXBContext**

This object is thread safe so you create this once and create all your instances of `Marshaller`, `Unmarshaller`, etc from it.

**Marshaller/Unmarshaller**

These objects are not thread safe, so you need to ensure that they are not being used by more than one thread at the same time.  Unless you are setting any properties on then you could always do:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo");
Object o = jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("nosferatu.xml"));
```